# How can I use WSL Ubuntu without be logged?

Tags: users, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have been experimenting with WSL Ubuntu terminal and I notice that `w` and `who` commands don't display any user, apparently I'm not logged but if I assure typing `whoami` and `id` actually display my user and ID

I lost my mind, Can I use bash without be logged? How can be possible? and if am not logged, How could the terminal know that's me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you invoke a Linux distribution in WSL1 or WSL2, you are automatically logged in as the default user you created when you installed the distribution. You can verify this with the `id` command.

That commands such as `w`, `who`, `logname` and `users` return no useful information is a known "feature" of WSL1 and WSL2. Why? Because by default, no `/var/run/utmp` is created.

See https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/573 for full details and a workaround.